# Change active object opacity from slider fabricjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I'm trying to change the opacity of active canvas object from slider, and I can't figure why this code doesn't work. I'm using fabric.js.

the html of the slider:

```
<input class="opacity-slider" type="range" max="100" min="0" step="1" value="100">
```

js:

```
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
$(document).on("change", ".opacity-slider", function (){
    var opacity = $(".opacity-slider").val();
    $(".slider-value").text(opacity);
    canvas.getActiveObject().setOpacity(opacity)
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. 
I didn't divide by 100 the opacity so

```
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
$(document).on("change", ".opacity-slider", function (){
    var opacity = jQuery(".opacity-slider").val();
    opacity = opacity / 100;
    jQuery(".slider-value").text(opacity);
    canvas.getActiveObject().setOpacity(opacity)
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```